# Django is asking to delete column, which does not even exists

Tags: python, mysql, django, phpmyadmin

I tried applying migrations, but Django asks me to delete a column that does not exist.

The error I get is:

```
OperationalError at /admin/location/location/
(1054, "Unknown column 'location_location.id' in 'field list'")
```

**`models.py`**

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

**`views.py`**

```py
def add_location(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LocationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = LocationForm()
    return render(request, 'add_location.html', {'form': form})
```

**`admin.py`**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Location

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Location)
```

I tried using the `--fake` option but it made it even worse.

**`Traceback`**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

The above exception ((1054, "Unknown column 'location_location.id' in 'field list'")) was the direct cause of the following exception:   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 686, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 2068, in changelist_view
    "selection_note": _("0 of %(cnt)s selected") % {"cnt": len(cl.result_list)},   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 376, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1867, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 87, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1398, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)   File "C:\Users\sarthak.lamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/location/location/ Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'location_location.id' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: Always post the whole error message with full traceback.

Comment: check your recent migration files.

Comment: Can you add your recent migration file codes?

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

first, delete migration file related to that `Location` models and re-migrate manually using below commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 # this value will generate after makemigration. It can be either 0001 or 0002 and so on.

python manage.py migrate
```